# Solr - How do i ranked first the results that contains all term queries?

Tags: solr, lucene

I use solr 4.9 and I need to change its Ranking system which first display the results that contains all term queries, then displayed another results based on tf/idf.

BTW, my solr's defaultSearchOperator is OR.

Comment: This is the behavior by default. What does your query look like, what scores are you seeing (in debugQuery) and what did you expect?

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh, The first and second result of my query, only contains two terms of the query (my query contains 3 terms like John Smith Pocahontas) with high frequency, but the third result contains all terms with low terms frequency. I want to display the third result in first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using power of [coord](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html#formula_coord) parameter in the [TF-IDF similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html) formula, we can get higher score for documents which contains more term queries.

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity;

public class EnhancedTFIDFSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {

    @Override
    public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
        float _coord = (overlap / (float)maxOverlap);    
        return (_coord * _coord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the field with `omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"` - this will exclude information about the frequency of the terms and their positions from scoring (since it's not available).

If you want to use the frequency and position for scoring in a different setting, use `copyField` to have an alternative field to use for queries requiring excluding termfreqs from the score.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine two queries, the first using AND and the second by OR operator, and then combine them with an OR. This would effectively return any results that contain all the search terms on top.

```
(+term1 +term2 +term3) OR (term1 term2 term3)
```

Comment: Thanks @spyk, your solution is right, but i want to change rank of results, not query!